# How to avoid SQL injection without PreparedStatements

Tags: java, sql

In my application I consume a XML web service that lets me query data based on a `WHERE` clause. I want to to implement a search function and the user input should go into the `WHERE` clause. The request looks like this:

```
<Query>
    <Selection>
        <sqlwhere>
            id IN (
                SELECT something
                FROM some_table
                WHERE something_different LIKE '%<user input>%'
                ESCAPE '\'
            )
        </sqlwhere>
    </Selection>
</Query>
```

The service wraps this part into the actual `SELECT` statement. The service might use either a Firebird or MS SQL Server database.

How can I easily escape the user input? Is it enough to escape apostrophes?

**Update**

Maybe I was a bit unclear. The part above is sent to the service and the service sends back the matching data in XML format. I am **not** the service maintainer. This means that I don't know about the underlying database and thus can't connect to it to make prepared statements.

I also can't fetch all data and filter it in my code because of performance issues. This is the only way I can talk to it (efficiently).

Comment: Why do people still keep trying to come up with their own ways to prevent sql injection? Stick to the standard of parameter based queries.

Comment: @Takarii Did you even read the question?

Comment: I did, and I still don't understand why you would do it this way. If the input hasnt been sanitized then its still a risk

Comment: What would be the better way then?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use parameters?

Comment: No, I would like to use parameters, but how?

Comment: One thing to do is to search input for single quotes (`'`), and double those. (Which is needed anyway.) However, still a bit risky.

Comment: Apache Commons had a function that did this, but it was removed, because it was not secure.

Comment: Implement black/white list of banned/allowed chars/reserved SQL words. Validate input against the defined list. Sanitize input - e.g. search best practices to sanitize input for SQL queries (single quotes into double etc.). Write a bunch of tests that cover simple SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Is it really necessary that the whole where expression is transmitted from the client? Why not transmit only the user input and hide the query as 'implementation detail'?

Comment: Because that's how the service works. And I can just use this service as it is.

Comment: The prevention of SQL injection is the job of the service maintainer. Client sided security measures are inherently unsecure.

Comment: Yes, I know, but he doesn't :( If he did, I should not be able to send parts of a SQL clause to the service... Nevertheless, I have to use it and I would like to provide at least a bit of security.

Comment: Probably the biggest favor you can do is tell him its a bad idea, and suggest the service be looked at.

Answer (score 0):

Build your query using the where clause coming from the service like this. Notice that I replaced the **'%< user input >%'** with **'%?%'**.

```
<Query>
    <Selection>
    <sqlwhere>
        id IN (
        SELECT something
        FROM some_table
        WHERE something_different LIKE '%?%'
        ESCAPE '\'
        )
    </sqlwhere>
    </Selection>
</Query>
```

Then, use `PreparedStatement` using this SQL and set the parameters as per user's input.

```
String sqlQuery = extractSQLFromService();//get the query and where clause here
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatment(sqlQuery);
ps.setString(1, userInput);
ps.execute();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isnt the `<user input>` part actual data? wouldn't this effectivly only provide `?` as the value?

Comment: I don't have a connection to the database and I don't know how the service uses my submitted `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I thought you are consuming the xml service, so you will be writing your query using this XML's **< sqlwhere >** value..

Comment: Consuming basically means to use, which can (in terms of data) be either upstream or downstream.

Comment: Even if you are just consuming it, you can replace the '%< userInput >%' tag with the '%?%' inside your code and then use it to run the query.

Comment: But then how would the service know what the userinput is? I assume the only way to communicate with the service is using this XML endpoint.

Comment: I create just the part that I showed you (`id IN (...`), but I don't execute it. This part is sent to the service, and the service returns the matching data in XML.

Comment: Is your job to validate the user Input or pass the user input to the end service ? Will it be possible to send the user Input in a separate tag in this XML to the service? Is the the service finalized and not open to modifications?